# invalid deployment target '6.0.0' for architecture 'arm64'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I want to archive my phonegap project . But I am getting  errors , I want to set my base SDK to 6.0. and CordovaLib wanted base sdk 7.0 . I am getting following error message :

```
error: invalid deployment target '6.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
```

when I remove the arm64 then again it is throwing the error . what is the correct solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check settings like below.

[image]

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check Build Settings like PREMKUMAR's answer.

However, if it's not solved, you will need to build CordovaLib library again.
I guess that library in your project is built only for arm64.